# R data reading and Plotting

Tags: r, database, optimization, plot, split

I am a just learner of R for Hydrological Modelling.I have flat file that is read by `readLines` and I want to grep and plot the values. the values are in thousands time interval, but the algorithim is just plotting the values against time of 0 to 9. here is the code

```
library(stringr)

x <- readLines("D:/Rlearning/Mohsin HYDRUS/Mohsin practice/Balance.out")

## Find all lines with [T]
a <- grep("[T]", x, value = T)
### Find all the lines that also say Time in that subset
b <- grep("Time", a , value = T)
#### Remove the first 2 lines in b (they didn't have a watbalR associated with it)
c <-  b[-c(1,2)]
### Find all WatBalR lines
d <- grep("WatBalR", x, value = T)
#### Put them together in a dataframe
data <- data.frame(time =c, watbalr = d)
#### Still need to filter numbers from each line don't know how to do it off the top of my head should be able to google it though like "pulling numbers from a string in R" or something.
#### Hopefully this helps

# Extract the numeric values from the two character vectors
# Use sub to omit all the characters before the first digit
times   <- sub("^.+?(\\d)", "\\1", c)
WatBlaR <- sub("^.+?(\\d)", "\\1", d)

# convert the characters to numbers
times   <- as.numeric(times)
WatBlaR <- as.numeric(WatBlaR)

# plot 
plot(x = times, y = WatBlaR)
```

the problem start when I converts the characters to numbers, one expert did this here some days before but its not resulting the accurate requirement.

I am new, I was trying to ask the question and was unable. I hope I will learn more from this site.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what is the expected output? It is not clear from the question what you mean with *I want to make values of Time and second column for WatBalR*. Are you looking for ways to aggregate those?

Comment: Thanks a lot, K..pradeep. Can you send me the material that will make my concept clear about this? You are awesome. I was stuck in it for the last week.  I am working on the optimization of this model. My first assignment is simple optimization techniques in R. Kindly send me packages name and material that I can Perform.     Thank you thank you very very very much. Now I will work on the complete file.

Comment: Please do not abuse of the comment system. If you want to provide more information, please edit your question.

Comment: Press the `edit` button on the bottom left of the question. Or [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43567836/edit).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to extract the numeric values from the character stings provided.

```
# Extract the numeric values from the two character vectors
# Use sub to omit all the characters before the first digit
times   <- sub("^.+?(\\d)", "\\1", c)
WatBlaR <- sub("^.+?(\\d)", "\\1", d)

# convert the characters to numbers
times   <- as.numeric(times)
WatBlaR <- as.numeric(WatBlaR)

# plot 
plot(x = times, y = WatBlaR)
```

[image]

A suggestion: do not use `c` as a variable name.  [`c`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/c.html) is a function for combining values into a vector or list.  Using `c` as a variable can cause problems.